# Imprimir Array de Imagenes en PHP Horizontalmente

Tags: php, html, array, imagen

tengo el siguiente código cuya función es cargar un array con un trozo de código html que imprime una imagen. Tal código hace su cometido, sin embargo al mostrarlo en pantalla, las imagenes se imprimen una debajo de otra como lo muestro a continuación. Requiero mostrarlas horizontalmente, para efectos de estética y usabilidad.

[image: Así se ve el resultado de lo que muestro]

el código a continuación.

```
<div id="selector">
        <?php

            $j = "<table>   
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href='agregar_cliente.html' class='fancybox fancybox.iframe'><img src='imgs/blue.png'></a>
                        <p>Habitación </p>
                    </td>           
                </tr>
            </table>";


                $array[10] = 1;

                for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
                    $array[$i]= $j; 
                }

                for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
                    echo "$array[$i]";
                }           
        ?>
</div>
```

¿Qué debo hacer para mostrarlo horizontalmente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La etiqueta tr es un renglón de tabla por lo que todo lo que esta dentro de cada uno de ellos ocupara un solo renglón. Aparte estas declarando una tabla en cada elemento del arreglo. 
Para corregirlo debes usar table y tr solo una vez, dentro del tr puedes colocar los td con las imágenes.

Para ilustracion:

La salida del código actual es :

```
    <tr><td>Imagen</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Imagen</td></tr>
    ....
    <tr><td>Imagen</td></tr>
```

La salida deseada es :

```
    <tr>
     <td>Imagen</td>
      <td>Imagen</td>
      ....
      <td>Imagen</td>

    </tr>
```

Prueba este codigo:

```
<?php

            $j = "
                    <td>
                        <a href='agregar_cliente.html' class='fancybox fancybox.iframe'><img src='imgs/blue.png'></a>
                        <p>Habitación </p>
                    </td>           

           ";


                $array[10] = 1;

                for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
                    $array[$i]= $j; 
                }
                 echo "<table><tr>"
                for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
                    echo "$array[$i]";
                }           
                echo"</tr></table>"
        ?>
```

Comment: Entiendo tu planteamiento, pero fíjate en el código que posteé, apenas utilizando un único <tr> y un único <td>. Realmente, el ciclo for que está más abajo es el encargado de mostrar las imagenes en pantalla.

Comment: Si me he fijado. Ya agregue el código que propongo para que notes la diferencia.

Comment: Luego de usar mi lógica un poco, y gracias a tu comentario, di con el problemas antes de que corrigieras tu respuesta. TE LO AGRADEZCO MUCHO! mis respetos.

Comment: No es nada, para eso estamos.  Te recomiendo que le des una revisada a css para el manejo de estilo y presentación, específicamente a grid layout. El uso de tablas ha caído en desuso ya que hace a la página poco flexible.